# Generate random points on the perimeter of a circle

Tags: circles, random

I have a circle of radius `r` and access to a random number generator.  What is a method to generate random `(x,y)` values distributed along the circle's perimeter?

Comment: Generate a random angle $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$.  Take $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method would be to generate a random angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Then convert from polar to Cartesian with $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta , r \sin \theta)$.

Note that if your random number generator returns a number $k \in [0,1]$ then $\theta = 2\pi k$.